# Get the type in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, reflection

can someone tell me how I can identify the type of an object in flex? In particular I have an array where I store multiple types in (but all UIComponents) now as I evaluate the array I want to find out whether I have a TextInput Control or a RadioButton. Does someone have an idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: just did it with "is": var b : Boolean = arr[i] is TextInput, is this the only one and best way to do this?

Comment: ObjectUtil.getClassInfo(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can either test against a particular class using the "is" operator or you can use flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName() (you pass it your object) - which will return a string of the fully qualified class name.

Comment: Ah yes -- getQualifiedClassName().  It's come in handy more than a few times.

Answer (score 4):

ITS WORKING :)

Following is the way I solved this issue

```
switch( true )
   {
    case item is Customer_SF:
     c = item as Customer_SF;
     break;

    case item is Opportunity:
     o = item as Opportunity; 
     break;

    case item is Product:
     o = ( item as Product )._opportunity;
     break;
    default:
     return true;
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

The operator "is" represents one option.

Then there is the operator [instanceof](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/operators.html#instanceof), which might or might not be useful depending on situation.

Also there's the ObjectUtil class with static method [getClassInfo](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/utils/ObjectUtil.html#getClassInfo()). This one returns more than just the object's class name.

Operator "typeof" unfortunately is useless for classes.

And, as Branden Hall already suggested, [flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/utils/package.html#getQualifiedClassName()).

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the "className" property.

It should return "TextInput" or "Button" depending the case

```
for each (var item:* in myArray)
{
    if(item.hasProperty('className'))
    {
        trace("item ["+i+"] is :" + item['className']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

here's some simple pseudo-code which demonstrates how to use the `is` operator for what you want to do:

```
for each (var item:* in myArray)
{
    if (item is TextInput)
        doSomethingWithTextInput(item as TextInput);
    else if (item is RadioButton)
        doSomethingWithRadioButton(item as RadioButton);
}
```

Comment: You can use Object instead of * unless you are expecting namespaces and other crazy items in your array.

Comment: Good point, I was just trying to make it as flexible as possible. In fact, if you know you're only going to have UIComponents or DisplayObjects, then you could use that.

Answer (score 1):

The `is` operator tests for type compatibility, yes.  From the docs, `is`:

> ... evaluates whether an object is
>   compatible with a specific data type,
>   class, or interface. Use the `is`
>   operator instead of the `instanceof`
>   operator for type comparisons. You can
>   also use the `is` operator to check
>   whether an object implements an
>   interface.

Other useful operators in this category are `typeof` (which returns a string representation of a primitive), `instanceof` (similar to `is`, but disregards interface compatibility) and `as`.  A great and complete list of ActionScript operators [is available here](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/operators.html#instanceof).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is using the "is" operator and use something like:

```
for( var i:int = 0; i < componentArr.length; i++ )
{
    var comp:UIComponent = componentArr[ i ];
    if( comp is DataGrid )
        // Handle DataGrid functionality here.
    else if (comp is DropDown )
        // Handle DropDown here
}
```

There is one problem with this approach, however.  Because "is" will return true for all descendant classes, you must put all of the descendant classes before their ancestors -- List must come before ListBase.  This can cause some annoyances.

```
// This is important to remember:
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
trace( mc is Sprite ); // true
```

There is one other option for cases where you want objects to be a member of a specific class (and not a descendant class): you can use the constructor property of the object and use a switch statement.

```
for( var i:int = 0; i < componentArr.length; i++ )
{
    var klass:Class = componentArr[ i ].constructor;

    switch( klass )
    {
        case DataGrid:
            // Handle DataGrid
            break;
        case Text:
            // Handle Text
            break;
        case NumericStepper:
             // Handle NumericStepper
            break;
        default:
             // Handle default
            break;

    }
}
```