# How can you get a type of a control at runtime?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

If any control (e.g. a DataGrid) is cast to UIComponent, how can you get its type at runtime?

Is this possible in Actionscript?

Comment: Maybe you need a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037265/get-the-type-in-flex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [use `getQualifiedClassName()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getQualifiedClassName%28%29) to get class name by the value as a string. You can [use `describeType()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType%28%29) to get the full information about class. And you can use [`constructor` property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html#constructor) to get class itself (to instantiate new instance by existing instance). Finally you can use [`is` operator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#is) to compare to the limited set of classes. Less recommended usage of [`typeof` operator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#typeof) which is rather obsolete.

To select the right way we need to know your particular problem.

Comment: @[Constantiner] Thanks for the detailed answer. Regarding my problem, I'm passing a control by reference to a component. What I'm actually trying to do is get the 'text' property of that control. But I think it would be better for SO knowledge base if I ask this as a separate question.