# How to get the argument's type of a function?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I want to guess the type of every argument from an anonymous function, something like mapping a class with reflection but just for a function, something like...

```
public function guessMyArgumentType(f:Function):void {

    for each (argument:* in f.arguments) {

        trace(typeof(argument));

    }

}
```

thanks!

**UPDATE**

Maybe this is insane but what about:

```
public static function guessMyArgumentType(f:Function):String {

    try {

        f(2);
        return "int";

    } catch (error:Error) {

        try {

            f("a");
            return "String";

        } catch (error:Error) {

            try {

                f(["uno", "dos", "tres"]);
                return "Array";

            } catch (error:Error) {

                try {

                    f(new ArrayCollection(["uno", "dos", "tres"]));
                    return "ArrayCollection";

                } catch (error:Error) {

                    return "WTF?";

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName()` as referenced here: [Get the type in flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037265/get-the-type-in-flex)

The arguments array is only accessible from inside a given function.

I don't think what you're asking is doable unless you do some crazy try/catch thing but that would always fail  if the argument were a custom class so it's not a great solution.

Another option would be adding some custom metadata which describes the function arguments. `[YourMeta(arg1="String",arg2="Array")]` above each function and then you get use `ObjectUtil.getClassInfo(f).metadata` to find that info. This requires you add YourMeta to the compiled metatags args.

There might be another way through something not published to ASDocs but I don't know about it.

Comment: +1 thanks for the meta data tip!. I'll solve this by passing the desire casting type as an argument.